# .NET Core 2.1 Calling different APIs with the same HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I have the following scenario: the user changes his/her mobile phone number, I should first verify this number by sending an SMS.

I should do it with API called Foo, then if the response from the Foo API is success, I should change this phone number using another API called Bar.

Here is my action in a WEB project:

```
[HttpPut]
public IActionResult ApprovePhone(PhoneEditVerificationVm model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (_gApiConnector.ReadFromFooApi("Verification", "CheckUserPhoneChangeApprovement", _filterModelHelper.GetQueryStringFromSimpleFilterModel(model)).IsHttpSuccess)
        {
            _gApiConnector.PutToBarApi("Persons", "EditUserPhone", model.VerificationCode);
            return Json(
                new
                {
                    success = true,
                    title = StringResource.Notification,
                    message = StringResource.PhoneNumberChangedSuccessfully
                });
        }
    }

        return Json(
            new
            {
                success = false,
                errorTitle = StringResource.Notification,
                errorText = ErrorMessageResource.Error,
                modelErrors = ModelState.AllErrors()
            });
}
```

Here are ReadFromFooApi and PutToBarApi methods, they call ReadFromApi and PutToApi methods respectively as shown below:

```
public ApiJsonResult ReadFromFooApi(string controllerName, string actionName, string query)
{
    return ReadFromApi(_contentApiOptions.BaseEndpoint, controllerName, actionName, query);
}

public ApiJsonResult PutToBarApi<T>(string controllerName, string actionName, T model)
{
    return PutToApi(_physicalApiOptions.BaseEndpoint, controllerName, actionName, model);
}
```

Here you can see a ReadFromApi method, there is no point of writing the implementation of PutToApi method because both methods are pretty much the same, the only difference is that instead of GetAsync(url) I use PutAsync(url, ...) method.

```
private ApiJsonResult ReadFromApi(string apiAddress, string controllerName, string actionName, string query)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName))
    {
        var client = _apiHttpClient.GetClient(apiAddress, _identityServerOptions.Authority, _identityServerOptions.ClientName, _identityServerOptions.ClientSecret);
        var url = controllerName;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(actionName))
            url += $"/{actionName}";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
            url += query.StartsWith("?") ? query : $"/{query}"
        var result = client?.Result?.GetAsync(url)?.Result;
        if (result != null)
        {
            return new ApiJsonResult { IsHttpSuccess = result.IsSuccessStatusCode, JsonData = result?.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync()?.Result };
        }
    }
    return new ApiJsonResult();
}
```

The problem is that in my startup.cs I have registered HttpContextAccessor as a sigleton service as shown below:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

So when I try to call a different API (PutToBarApi in my case) method after the first one, this exception is thrown.

[image]

I tried to find a good workaround for that problem that doesn't change my code and architecture dramatically but nothing has worked so far. So any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think HttpContextAccessor registration is the problem? I doubt that since there is an extension on `IServiceCollection` that does exactly the same. (`AddHttpContextAccessor()`). Which line throws the error? More information about this would be handy.

Comment: Maybe you're right HttpContextAccessor may not be a problem, I did some more research in my code and found the following:
services.AddTransient<IApiHttpClient, ApiHttpClient>();

Which can cause what is happening currently I think.

Comment: The exception is thrown on the following line: var result = client?.Result.PutAsync(url, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))?.Result; In PutToApi<T> method.

Comment: For this error and your code, it seems you change the base address for `ReadFromFooApi` and `PutToBarApi`. As the error indicates, you should not change the `HttpClient` properties after sending request. You could initialize new `HttpClient` for `ReadFromFooApi` and `PutToBarApi` separately.